# How to get the UI displayed text in an enum?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

Ex. how do I get the name displayed in the UI of this enum? `bpy.context.preferences.system.audio_channels`

It is returning ex. `'SURROUND51'`, but I need `5.1 Surround`.
How do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From the `bl_rna`**

*Will hunt down some links re this and possible dupe, ... tis getting harder and harder to find posts that I'm sure I've seen, even written*

Can look up any property definition from its `bl_rna` .. in this case from the instance

```
>>> prefs = C.preferences
>>> enum_def = prefs.system.bl_rna.properties["audio_channels"]
>>> for i in enum_def.enum_items:
...     i.name, i.identifier, i.description
...     
('Mono', 'MONO', 'Set audio channels to mono')
('Stereo', 'STEREO', 'Set audio channels to stereo')
('4 Channels', 'SURROUND4', 'Set audio channels to 4 channels')
('5.1 Surround', 'SURROUND51', 'Set audio channels to 5.1 surround sound')
('7.1 Surround', 'SURROUND71', 'Set audio channels to 7.1 surround sound')
```

for example to make a look up table

```
>>> lut = {i.identifier : i.name for i in enum_def.enum_items}
>>> prefs.system.audio_channels
'STEREO'

>>> lut[prefs.system.audio_channels]
'Stereo'
```

Comment: Oh, wow. Complicated stuff. I'm glad I asked, I would never have found this solution. 

I wonder if bf devs will accept look-up this in a UI script. Time will show. 

Thank you.